# Postfix milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from 4.7.1 Service unavailable - try again later

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, dkim

I am running `postfix-2.11` version and recently i have added `dkim-milter-2.8`

Postfix configuration:

```
# DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8892
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8892
```

TCP socket Listening ( Daemon running as `dkim-milter` user )

```
[root@mail postfix]# netstat -nalp | grep dkim-filter
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8892              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      19651/dkim-filter
```

Group permission:

```
[root@mail postfix]# id dkim-milter
uid=494(dkim-milter) gid=494(dkim-milter) groups=494(dkim-milter),12(mail),89(postfix)

[root@mail postfix]# id postfix
uid=89(postfix) gid=89(postfix) groups=89(postfix),12(mail),494(dkim-milter)

[root@mail postfix]# id mail
uid=8(mail) gid=12(mail) groups=12(mail),89(postfix),494(dkim-milter)
```

Postfix /var/spool/postfix permission:

```
[root@mail postfix]# ls -l /var/spool/postfix
total 56
drwx------.  2 postfix root     4096 Mar 18 12:00 active
drwx------.  2 postfix root     4096 Mar 18 06:10 bounce
drwx------.  2 postfix root     4096 Feb 20  2014 corrupt
drwx------. 18 postfix root     4096 Mar 14 13:56 defer
drwx------. 18 postfix root     4096 Mar 14 13:56 deferred
drwx------.  2 postfix root     4096 Feb 20  2014 flush
drwx------.  2 postfix root     4096 Feb 20  2014 hold
drwx------.  2 postfix root     4096 Mar 18 12:00 incoming
drwx-wx---.  2 postfix postdrop 4096 Mar 18 11:56 maildrop
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root    root     4096 Mar 18 11:43 pid
drwx------.  2 postfix root     4096 Mar 18 11:43 private
drwx--x---.  2 postfix postdrop 4096 Mar 18 11:43 public
drwx------.  2 postfix root     4096 Feb 20  2014 saved
drwx------.  2 postfix root     4096 Mar 16 11:56 trace
```

If i send email from google to my mail server, i am getting following error with `reject` But if i disable `DKIM` from postfix, everything works great! I don't know why dkim not handling incoming email? I tried to search everywhere on internet but none of them has solution.

```
Mar 18 10:21:05 164-172 postfix/cleanup[18029]: 9694A820891: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from mail-pd0-f169.google.com[209.85.192.169]: 4.7.1 Service unavailable - try again later; from=<someuser@gmail.com> to=<john@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-pd0-f169.google.com>
```

Comment: What's the complete output of `grep 9694A820891 maillog`? Have you setup logging for dkim-milter? Can you switch to [opendkim](http://opendkim.org/)? [DKIM homepage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dkim-milter/) indicated that the project has been replaced by OpenDKIM...

Comment: @masegaloeh - You are right `dkim-milter` is broken, I have installed `opendkim` and it works! without any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution:

As @masegaloeh said `dkim-milter` discontinue. Just installed `OpenDKIM` and problem has been resolved.